# Bash Script not running properly from C++ code

Tags: c++, bash, timeout, popen

I have a tiny bash script that looks like this:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    /usr/bin/timeout 4 /usr/bin/sh -c 'echo | openssl s_client -connect company.io:443'
```

This script will get a certificate, if it can not get the certificate within 4 seconds it quits.

If I call this script from the command line it works perfectly.  But if I call this from my C++ code using popen it seems to ignore the timeout and will take a full 20 seconds for the openssl timeout to terminate.  Here is the code to execute it.

```
    if(!(in = popen(<myBashScriptName>, "r"))){
        return ecr;
    }

    stringstream ss("");
    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in) != NULL ){
        ss << buff;
    }

    auto rc = pclose(in);
```

Why won't it do the 4 second timeout if I call this directly from c++ code.

Comment: What did you write for <myBashScriptName>? How did you use quotes for popen?

Comment: The script name is getcertificate.  So I used
popen("/home/login/bin/getcertificate");

Comment: I think you should use popen("/usr/bin/timeout 4 /usr/bin/sh -c 'echo | openssl s_client -connect company.io:443'","r'); I haven't escaped all quotes correctly.

Comment: Were you able to run it?

Comment: I ran it and it did not work, ignored the timeout, took a full 20 seconds.